# rails cannot save submitted result in DB

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have four controllers - users, categories, stories and comments. My problem is with comments. When I submit a comment @comment.save is false and I can't understand where is the problem. My table in DB for Comment has content, user_id, story_id. Here is part of my code:

```
def new
  @comment = Comment.new
  @story = Story.find(params[:story_id])
end

def create
  @story = Story.find(params[:story_id])
  if current_user
    @comment = current_user.comments.create(params[:comment])
  end

  if @comment.save
    flash[:success] = "Successfull added comment"
    redirect_to story_path(@story)
  else
    render 'new'
  end
end
```

show.html.erb for StoriesController:

```
<b><%= @story.title %></b> <br/><br/>

<%= @story.content %> <br/><br/>

<% @story.comments.each do |comment| %>
  <b>Comment:</b>
  <%= comment.content %>
<% end %>

<%= form_for([@story, @story.comments.build]) do |f| %>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :content %><br />
    <%= f.text_area :content %>
  </div>
  <div class="actions">
    <%= f.submit "Add" %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

comment.rb:

```
class Comment < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :content, :story_id, :user_id 
  belongs_to :story
  belongs_to :user

  validates :content, :presence => true
  validates :story_id, :presence => true
  validates :user_id, :presence => true

  default_scope :order => 'comments.created_at DESC'
end
```

story.rb

```
class Story < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :title, :content, :category_id 
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :category
  has_many :comments

  validates :title, :presence => true
  validates :content, :presence => true
  validates :user_id, :presence => true

  default_scope :order => 'stories.created_at DESC'
end
```

**UPDATE**
When I use save! I have an error message Story cannot be blank.

Comment: Consider using save! at least for now, so that an exception will be thrown with more information. Also, check out the @comment.errors (or use a form helper that prints these errors out for you in the html for more useful feedback)

Comment: Updated with models. When I use save! I have an error message Story cannot be blank.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set the story for the comment your are building since (as you've obviously worked out), the story in question is given by `params[:story_id]`. That story id isn't magically going to find its way into the `params[:comment]` hash. You could either do

```
@comment = @story.comments.build(params[:comment])
@comment.user = current_user
```

or create the comment on the user and then set its story.